# How do I filter for a specific value from a nested list in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How do I return only the nested list element in orders with :id matching 127? How do I search for it within the list, "orders", without knowing it's position (just searching by value)?

```
orders
[[id: 123, ship_to: :NC, net_amount: 100.0],
 [id: 124, ship_to: :OK, net_amount: 35.5],
 [id: 125, ship_to: :TX, net_amount: 24.0],
 [id: 126, ship_to: :TX, net_amount: 44.8],
 [id: 127, ship_to: :NC, net_amount: 25.0],
 [id: 128, ship_to: :MA, net_amount: 10.0],
 [id: 129, ship_to: :CA, net_amount: 102.0],
 [id: 139, ship_to: :NC, net_amount: 50.0]]
```

Desired result: [id: 127, ship_to: ...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.find/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#find/3) for this. It takes an enumerable (like the `orders` list you have here) and a function and returns the first element for which the function returns a truthy value (non-`false` and non-`nil`).

```
Enum.find(orders, fn order -> {:id, 127} in order end)
```

This is just one possible solution; there are many possible ones :). For example, you could use the `[]` syntax with `Enum.find/2` as well:

```
Enum.find(orders, fn order -> order[:id] == 127 end)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was just what I needed!